# Coefficients of pullback connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am learning about connections using Lee's Intro to Riemannian Manifolds, and I am confused regarding the coefficients of the pullback connection. For the setting, let $(M,g) $ be a Riemannian manifold and let $\nabla$ be a connection on $M$. From Prop 4.7 in Lee's book, if we have two local frames $(E_i)$ and $(\tilde{E}_j)$ related by a matrix $A^j_i$, then the transformation law for the connection coefficients is:
$$
\tilde{\Gamma}^k_{ij} = (A^{-1})^k_pA^q_iA^r_j\Gamma^p_{qr} +  (A^{-1})^k_pA^q_iE_q(A^p_j).
\tag{1}
$$

I showed this as indicated in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703540/transformation-law-for-connection-coefficients), using the definition of the connection coefficients. Further, Lee introduces the pullback connection by a diffeomorphism $\varphi:M \to \tilde{M}$ between $(M,g) $ and $(\tilde{M},\tilde{g})$ by:
$$
(\varphi^*\tilde{\nabla})_X Y = (\varphi^{-1})_*(\tilde{\nabla}_{\varphi_*X}(\varphi_*Y)),
$$
for any vector fields $X,Y$ on $M$. I obtained that the coefficients of the pullback connection satisfy an analog relation to the transformation law above. If $x^i$ are coordinates on $M$ and $\tilde{x}^j$ are coordinates on $\tilde{M}$ and denoting the coefficients of $\varphi^*\tilde{\nabla}$ by ${}^{\varphi^*\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^k_{ij}$ and those of $\tilde{\nabla}$ by ${}^{\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^k_{ij}$, I obtained:
$$
{}^{\varphi^*\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^k_{ij} = 
\frac{\partial \varphi^{-1,k}}{\partial \tilde{x}^p}
\frac{\partial \varphi^q}{\partial x^i}
\frac{\partial \varphi^r}{\partial x^j}{}^{\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^p_{qr}
+
\frac{\partial \varphi^{-1,k}}{\partial \tilde{x}^p}
\frac{\partial \varphi^q}{\partial x^i}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^q}\left( \frac{\partial \varphi^p}{\partial x^j} \right).\tag{2}
$$

Now, according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458136/pulling-back-affine-or-not-connections) and the follow-up discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713830/understanding-the-coefficients-of-a-pullback-connection), the coefficients of the pullback connection take the simpler form (using my notation):
$$
{}^{\varphi^*\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^k_{ij} = {}^{\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^k_{im}(d\varphi)^m_j.\tag{3}
$$
As I understand it, $d\varphi$ is the differential of $\varphi$, so in components it simply writes $\frac{\partial \varphi^m}{\partial x^j}$, and we are far from (2).

**Question 1**:Does each expression for ${}^{\varphi^*\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^k_{ij} $ apply to a particular case? Which is the correct one?
(This will probably help me understand better the situation in [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4871806/verify-that-surfaces-are-isometric-by-looking-at-pullback-of-levi-civita-connect) regarding developable surfaces)

**Question 2**: More general question: (1) and (2) are identical when $\varphi$ is a change of variable from $M$ to $M$. Is it correct to view a change of variable as a pullback? Do the pullback relations always reduce to the relevant change of variable formulas when the map $\varphi$ is a change of variable? For instance, the components of the pullback of a 2-covariant tensor match the components of the tensor after a change of variable.

Thanks a lot for the help.

**Edit**: I obtained (2) by applying the pointwise pullback on basis vectors, with $F = \varphi$:
\begin{align}
(F^*\tilde{\nabla})_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Large\vert_{p}}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) &= dF^{-1}_{F(p)}\left[ \tilde{\nabla}_{dF_p\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\large\vert_{p}\right)} \left( dF_p\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)\right)\right]\\
&= dF^{-1}_{F(p)}\left[ \tilde{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial F^k}{\partial x^i}\Large\vert_{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^k}} \left( \frac{\partial F^l}{\partial x^j}\biggr\vert_{p}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde{x}^l}\right)\right]\\
&= dF^{-1}_{F(p)}\left[ \frac{\partial F^k}{\partial x^i}\biggr\vert_{p}  \tilde{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^k}} \left( \frac{\partial F^l}{\partial x^j}\biggr\vert_{p}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde{x}^l}\right) \right]\\
&= dF^{-1}_{F(p)}\left[ \frac{\partial F^k}{\partial x^i}\biggr\vert_{p} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^k}\biggr\vert_{F(p)} \left( \frac{\partial F^l}{\partial x^j}\right)
\frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde{x}^l}
+
\frac{\partial F^l}{\partial x^j}\biggr\vert_{p}
\tilde{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^k}}
\left( \frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde{x}^l}\right) \right)\right]\\
&= dF^{-1}_{F(p)}\left[ \frac{\partial F^k}{\partial x^i}\biggr\vert_{p} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^k}\biggr\vert_{F(p)} \left( \frac{\partial F^l}{\partial x^j}\right)
\frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde{x}^l}
+
\frac{\partial F^l}{\partial x^j}\biggr\vert_{p}
{}^{\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^m_{kl} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^m}\right)\right]\\
&= \left[ \frac{\partial F^k}{\partial x^i}\biggr\vert_{p} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^k}\biggr\vert_{F(p)} \left( \frac{\partial F^m}{\partial x^j}\right)
+
\frac{\partial F^l}{\partial x^j}\biggr\vert_{p}
{}^{\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^m_{kl} \right)\right] dF^{-1}_{F(p)} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^m} \right)\\
&= \left[ \frac{\partial F^k}{\partial x^i}\biggr\vert_{p} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^k}\biggr\vert_{F(p)} \left( \frac{\partial F^m}{\partial x^j}\right)
+
\frac{\partial F^l}{\partial x^j}\biggr\vert_{p}
{}^{\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^m_{kl} \right)\right] \frac{\partial F^{-1,r}}{\partial \tilde{x}^m} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^r} \\
&= \left( \frac{\partial F^{-1,r}}{\partial \tilde{x}^m}\biggr\vert_{F(p)} \frac{\partial F^k}{\partial x^i}\biggr\vert_{p} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^k}\biggr\vert_{F(p)} \left( \frac{\partial F^m}{\partial x^j}\right)
+
\frac{\partial F^{-1,r}}{\partial \tilde{x}^m}\biggr\vert_{F(p)} \frac{\partial F^k}{\partial x^i}\biggr\vert_{p}
\frac{\partial F^l}{\partial x^j}\biggr\vert_{p}
{}^{\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^m_{kl} \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^r} \\
&= \left( \frac{\partial F^{-1,k}}{\partial \tilde{x}^p}\biggr\vert_{F(p)} \frac{\partial F^q}{\partial x^i}\biggr\vert_{p} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^q}\biggr\vert_{F(p)} \left( \frac{\partial F^p}{\partial x^j}\right)
+
\frac{\partial F^{-1,k}}{\partial \tilde{x}^p}\biggr\vert_{F(p)} \frac{\partial F^q}{\partial x^i}\biggr\vert_{p}
\frac{\partial F^r}{\partial x^j}\biggr\vert_{p}
{}^{\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^p_{qr} \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} \\
&= {}^{F^*\tilde{\nabla}}\Gamma^k_{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} \\
\end{align}

Comment: It might help that the Jacobian of your inverse differomorphism is indeed the inverse of the Jacobian diffeomorphism.

Comment: @Chris But even then I don't see how the terms would cancel out... (regarding the 1st question)

Comment: I’m actually not sure how your equation 2. Can you show your calculation?

Comment: @Chris I edited the question with my calculation!

Comment: Just to clarify, are confused as to why these two are equivalent?

Comment: @Chris Yes, for example, I used (2) to determine the Christoffel symbols of the Euclidean connection in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in polar coordinates from the Christoffel in Cartesian coordinates. I obtain the good result. But in Cartesian they are all 0, so clearly (3) yields 0 for the polar coordinates too, which is not right.

I saw (3) in a few sources, but I'm not sure if it applies with some conditions.

Comment: $(3)$ feels fishy to me in general, but i will think about it some.

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the other post. The two formulisms are compatible, although you can say the other post has much less information.

First, **the other post is using a different convention** of the Christoffel symbols -- he differentiates the first vector field with respect to the second. So your $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ is his $\Gamma_{ji}^k$. Then his formula, as you correctly tried to interpret, is
$$
{}^{\varphi^*\tilde\nabla}\Gamma_{ij}^k =\frac{\partial \varphi^q}{\partial x^i} {}^{\tilde\nabla}\Gamma_{qj}^k .
$$
This would match with your formula (2) if you group terms as
$$
{}^{\varphi^*\tilde\nabla}\Gamma_{ij}^k =\frac{\partial \varphi^q}{\partial x^i}\Big(\frac{\partial\varphi^{-1,k}}{\partial \tilde x^p} 
\frac{\partial\varphi^{r}}{\partial x^j}{}^{\tilde\nabla}\Gamma_{qr}^p 
+ \frac{\partial\varphi^{-1,k}}{\partial \tilde x^p} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde x^q}\big(\frac{\partial\varphi^{p}}{\partial x^j}\big)
\Big).
$$
So the compatibility comes from
$$
{}^{\tilde\nabla}\Gamma_{qj}^k=\frac{\partial\varphi^{-1,k}}{\partial \tilde x^p} 
\frac{\partial\varphi^{r}}{\partial x^j}{}^{\tilde\nabla}\Gamma_{qr}^p 
+ \frac{\partial\varphi^{-1,k}}{\partial \tilde x^p} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde x^q}\big(\frac{\partial\varphi^{p}}{\partial x^j}\big).
$$

The thing to note is that $i, j, k$ are indices on $M$ for $x^i, x^j, x^k$, and $p, q, r$ are indices on $\tilde M$ for $\tilde x^p, \tilde x^q, \tilde x^r$. So the notation
$$
{}^{\tilde\nabla}\Gamma_{qj}^k
$$
is not very well-defined, since it involves both sets of variables. Your formula would be a correct working out of it by
$$
\varphi_*\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} = \frac{\partial \varphi^r}{\partial x^j} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde x^r},\quad
(\varphi^{-1})_*\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde x^p} = \frac{\partial \varphi^{-1,k}}{\partial \tilde x^p} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}.
$$
I believe you can fill in this part.

From this point of view, the other post is only saying that $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ is tensorial in the index $i$, since that is the index for $X$ in $\nabla_X Y$.

Now about your **Question 2**, it is not a coincidence that formula (1) and (2) are identical. A change of variable is a diffeomorphism on the coordinate neighborhood. So a pullback by a diffeomorphism and a change of variables are about the same, at least locally.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I think that's exactly the answer I was hoping for. Thanks a lot!